# What to do if my university doesn't have a research group in my area?

Tags: graduate-admissions, thesis, research-undergraduate

I am studying electrical engineering and I am really interested in electromagnetics and photonics. Unfortunately, my university doesn't have research groups in these fields so I am unable to pursue my final year project doing research in these areas. What should I do?
One possibility is to gain research experience in the research groups of my university, which are mathematics applied to energy and telecommunications, and quantum computing. I am not convinced about this option. This would only serve as an introduction to research and improve my chances of getting accepted for a good masters program where I would be able to study the former two areas.

Comment: In what country are you intending to study in grad school?

Comment: Getting research experience period is useful. And who knows, you might find that research quite interesting as well.

Comment: There is nothing you can do. You just need to make use of what is available to you.  This is the same everywhere.  I wish I am at a university with lots of $$$.  What to do if I can't get the resource I need to achieve my interests or research goals? same question.

Comment: @Buffy mainly Canada and US, although there are very good photonics programs in the UK and in switzerland at EPFL or ETHZ. These universities are very competitive though.

Comment: I know doing research in undergrad is a plus and not every student that applies to grad school does it, but I don't know by how much doing research in A will make be a better candidate for a masters focused on B. Maybe it's a big difference, maybe it isn't. If it isn't, I should be looking for a solution to my problem.